# Session authentication with cookie: security issue

Tags: security, session, authentication, cookies

I have a simple "session authentication" mechanism:

- each time a user logs in a session it's created on database server side, and it's session id is set encrypted as a "session cookie" to the client
- on logout or browser instance closing, the session is either deleted or invalidated

I've read and understood that by stealing a cookie encrypting the session id within an active session one steals another identity, and for this reason permanent cookie should not be used.

Still, **even if i used a cookie with an short expiration date the theft can still happen within it**. Are there other steps to avoid this problem?
It's legit to just use a short expiration date (if so, what is a decent time frame?), or are there other complementary technique to work around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice for session cookies is to not set an expiry time so that they are valid for the browser session. If you set an expiry time, the cookie becomes persistent, will be stored on disk on the client and so on - it increases the overall risk.

You are right that anybody that has the cookie can impersonate the user. To avoid that, you want to have the cookie set as `httpOnly` to avoid Javascript access (XSS) and `secure` so that it is only sent over https.

While there are depths to correct session management, it doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to encrypt the session id. What is the purpose of that encryption? The session id should just be a large random number (possibly encoded into a shorter string, but still), there should be no need to encrypt it.

The generic advice around session management is to not implement it yourself. There are too many pitfalls, and pretty much all frameworks (or languages) have a solid implementation that you can just use reasonably securely. Avoiding all the potential vulnerabilities is hard.

Comment: about the "encryption" maybe i'm just not using the right terminology... as you said, it' probably enough to make it not human readable

Comment: But isn't an unencrypted session ID easier to guess?